# how do i add auto numbering with each fetching row?

Tags: php, while-loop

how do I add auto numbering with each fetching row? I want auto to add a new number as a serial number with each fetching row from the mysql database?

```
<?php
$i=0;
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cart
WHERE email='".$_SESSION['email']."'");

while($rowdata1=mysql_fetch_array($query))
$i++;
{
?>

<?php echo $i ?> // here i want to add serial number
<?php echo $rowdata1['itemcode']?>
<?php echo $rowdata1['product']?>
<img src="admin/<?php echo $rowdata1['image'] ?>"/>
<?php echo $rowdata1['price']?>
<?php echo $rowdata1['size']?></font>
<?php echo $rowdata1['total']?>
<?php echo $rowdata1['date']?>
<?php $rowdata1['blueexnum']?>
<?php echo $rowdata1['blueexstatus']?>
<?php }?>
```

The problem is solved now thanks

```
<?php
$i=0;
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cart
WHERE email='".$_SESSION['email']."'");
while($rowdata1=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
$i++;
?>
```

Comment: Hi Edge, what should a serial number look like?

Comment: @michi it should be like this `1,2,3,4... so on`?

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there, change your code to:

```
$h = '';
$i = 0;
while($rowdata1=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $i++;
    $h .= "$i) $rowdata1[itemcode] $rowdata1[product] ";
    $h .= "<img src=\"admin/$rowdata1[image]\"/> ";
    $h .= "$rowdata1[price] $rowdata1[size] $rowdata1[total] ";
    $h .= "$rowdata1[date] $rowdata1[blueexnum] $rowdata1[blueexstatus]<br />";
}
echo $h;
```

Of course, you can use `echo` as you did in your code. It's usually faster though to build the whole string in `$h`and echo it out as a whole.
You might want to use a `<table>` to display the data in a more structured way.

Answer (score 0):

Use mysql to do that for you.
Change your query to

```
SET @row_number=0;
SELECT @row_number:=@row_number+1 AS row_number, cart.*
FROM cart
WHERE email=?"
```

Then when you use it, just echo as just another column

```
<?php echo $rowdata1['row_number']?>
```

On a side note, don't use $_SESSION['email'] without escaping it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php>
    //set counter to 1
    $counter = 1;
    <thead>
    <tr>
    th>No.</th>
    <th>REGISTRATION #</th>
    <th>SURNAME<`enter code here`/th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $counter; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo htmlentities($class['registration']); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo htmlentities($class['sirname']); ?></td>
    </tr>
    $counter++;
    </tbody>

?>
```